# Suppress errors when using global function

Tags: php, functions, globals, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm using the NinjaForms plugin which defines a [`Ninja_Forms()`](https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/forms/) global function.

Although I can call it without problem, I still get a warning/error

> Undefined function 'Ninja_Forms'.

If this were a variable I'd use `global foo` to suppress that.

How do I do that for a global function - i.e. **is there a `global` equivalent for functions?**

Comment: Global isn’t a magic way to suppress errors. You have a problem with your code that actually needs to be fixed. Where and how are you using the function?

Comment: I'm using the function as advertised by its author. I want to know what is the "global" equivalent for functions, if at all. The downvote was unnecessary.

Comment: There isn’t one. The premise of your question is incorrect, which is why I’m saying that something else is wrong. And you didn’t answer my question: Where and how are you using the function?

Comment: That is irrelevant to my question - which was whether there is a global equivalent for functions? If not, then *that's the answer*. I don't like globals, but sometimes it's necessary/convenient. NinjaForms is a very popular plugin, so I'm not doing anything wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. If you weren’t there’d be no error. But you’re clearly not actually interested in figuring out what it is, having invented your own solution and refused to provide any information that could be used to help. For your own sake I hope that you’re less needlessly stubborn the next time you ask for help.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, appreciated! :-)

Answer (score -1):

According to comments above, there is no "global" equivalent for functions. So I'm just gonna live with the warning, since everything works.

Comment: Thanks to @JacobPeattie for his incredible help. This is the correct answer to the question BTW - according to @JacobPeattie in wordpress/php there is no `global` equivalent for functions. So you can live with the warning or restructure your code.